# concat two columns and store in a new column in a csv

Tags: python

i am not getting the desired expected output.I have to concat "itemnumber" column with "imagename" column and save into another column "image" in that csv. Eg B001_B001 .It also creates a duplicate image "B001_B001.jpg" in the image folder.

My input is:

```
  ItemNumber  UPC Keyword ImageName ImageWChain Description     
0       B001  123     XYZ      B001        B001       Test1  
1       B002  456     GDH      B002        B002       Test2 
2       B003  789     GFR      B003        B003       Test3
```

and my expected output is:

```
  ItemNumber  UPC Keyword ImageName ImageWChain Description      Image
0       B001  123     XYZ      B001        B001       Test1  B001_B001
1       B002  456     GDH      B002        B002       Test2  B002_B002
2       B003  789     GFR      B003        B003       Test3  B003_B003
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import os
from os.path import splitext        # splits name & extension from a file
import shutil                       # making a duplicate copy of a file
import logging

class Image:
    def image_fix(self):

        #open and read csv
        with open('rosary.csv') as csvfile:

        #create list for sku, old_imagename_column_1, old_imagename_column_1 
        #and renamed new_imagename
                keyList = []                      #for ItemNumber
                itemList = []                     #for ImageName
                itemList1 = []                    #for ImageWChain
                renamedList = []                  #for Renamed NEW_ImageName

                spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

        #storing all the columns into list
                for row in spamreader:
                    keyList.append(row[0])
                    itemList.append(row[3])
                    itemList1.append(row[4])

                    renamedList.append(row[6])

        # processing for ImageName
        for item in enumerate(itemList):
            oldFileName = name
            newFileName = '{}_{}{}'.format(name, keyList[item[0]])


            # check if the image file existsin image folder for ImageName column

            if (os.path.isfile(oldFileName)):

                    shutil.copy2(oldFileName, newFileName)     #make a duplicate image of every itemname
                    renamedList[item[0]] = '{}_{}{}'.format(oldFileName, keyList[item[0]])


            # write the final output in new csv
            with open('rosary.csv','wb') as my_csv:
                 csvWriter = csv.writer(my_csv,delimiter=',')
                 for row in zip(keyList, itemList, itemList1, renamedList):
                     # printing row in order
                     print(row[0] + '\t' + '\t' + row[3] + '\t' + '\t' + 
                           row[4] + '\t' + '\t' + row[6])
                     csvWriter.writerow(row)

if __name__=="__main__":
    obj = Image()
    obj.image_fix()
```

Comment: what's your code's problem?

Comment: I am not getting expected output like in the image. :(

Comment: what did you get, can you past it into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('rosary.csv')
df['Image'] = df.ImageName + "_" + df.ImageWChain
df.to_csv('rosary.csv')

>>> df
       Unnamed: 0 Description ImageName ImageWChain ItemNumber Keyword  UPC      Image
0           0       Test1      B001        B001       B001     XYZ  123  B001_B001
1           1       Test2      B002        B002       B002     GDH  456  B002_B002
2           2       Test3      B003        B003       B003     GFR  789  B003_B003
```

To make a new image copy:

```
for old_image, new_image in zip(df.ImageName, df.Image):
    if (os.path.isfile(old_image)):
        shutil.copy2(old_image, new_image)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Alexander.... it should also create a duplicate image B001_B001, B002_B002 and B003_B003 in the image folder...There is B001,B002,B003 image in the folder

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution improving on Alexander's answer, which would work for all column names and all data types, and drop the index in the output file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('rosary.csv')

df['Image'] = df['ImageName'].astype(str) + "_" + df['ImageWChain'].astype(str)

df.to_csv('rosary.csv', index=False)
```